# Change message if database error

Tags: database, error-message

Is it possible to route to a nice "Site is currently offline" error page if there is an issue connecting to the database?

Currently you'll see something like the message below which isn't very customer friendly.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Craft canâ€™t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php.")
```

Comment: The part about this that always bugs me the most is the weird non-apostrophe in `canâ€™t`.

Answer (score 1):

On a default Craft install if I'm logged out and hit the front-end of the site with purposefully messed up database credentials, I get a nicely styled Craft 404 page if there is no `craft/templates/404.html` and a front-end 404 page if there is.

I believe the issue is that you've got your own front-end 404 template that's also trying to access the database and it can't.

So basically the first error is thrown (can't access the database), then another error happens (I *really* can't access the database) when trying to tell you about the first error.

By this point, Yii thinks the error has already been handled, so it falls back to [CApplication->displayException()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/base/CApplication.php#L924).  I assume in this case, some content header or encoding isn't set properly and you see the garbled ’ character.

So until/if we can think of a way to guard against this scenario, your best bet is to make sure that your 404 template isn't triggering a database call.